# Trying to name date/time stamp as file name in python

Tags: python, filenames

So im trying to make a raspberry pi project to take photos on schedule i have chrontab downpacked a little bit but i wanna name the files with the time/date they were taken at.

```
import datetime
dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m.%d.%Y - %H:%M")
print (dt)
```

- Works like a charm but i cant save the "dt" variable as the name of the file.

  import datetime
  dt = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m.%d.%Y - %H:%M")
  print (dt)
  p = open('dt'.txt , 'w+')

11.03.2021 - 01:21

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 4, in <module>
     p = open('dt'.txt , 'w+')
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'txt'
```

What am i doing wrong????????

Comment: `p = open('{}.txt'.format(dt) , 'w+') ` do you mean this?

Comment: Use `p = open(f"{dt}.txt", 'w+')`

Comment: @MSH i feel so dumb because i saw that exact example on another thread but couldn't get it to work but i copy and paste yours it works perfectly have a great day bro!!!!